# HTML5 FileSystem: How to revoke granted quota?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use `window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota()` to get disk quota. Everything works as it should but I can't revoke already granted quota for debug purposes. Seems there is no API for that. And more over I can't find how it can be done through Chrome interface. I've found this link: `chrome://quota-internals/` but it just provides a read only info. I am developing chrome extension and even uninstalling/installing of it doesn't help. Who knows how to reset local disk storage settings for the site (or extension) or even the storage as a whole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug [crbug.com/121463](http://crbug.com/121463)

Comment: Yes! It looks that File API is not mature enough.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to: `chrome://settings/content`
2. Under cookies click: `All Cookies and Site Data`
3. Filter down to the host you want to revoke access for
4. Click through the permissions (filesystem, database, cookie, etc.) you want to remove.

[image: rm permissions]

There is also this:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#reset

Comment: Thank you for pointing this new (?) feature of Chrome interface but I still can't find how to reset quotas for Chrome Extensions (not sites).

Comment: This is not working anymore.... no such item shows up in Chrome's `settings/content` (v67)... I remember being able to revoke access granted in the past... must be a bug. The linked white paper mentions `chrome://settings/cookies` which doesn't even exist anymore?